# Share App on Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I want to share my iPhone app on Facebook.
But I am getting one error as "Sorry the application you are using is misconfigured for Facebook integration. Please download the newest version of the application". To solve this I am going through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ link.
But its not solved still.My question is, to share my application on Facebook is it necessary to have Facebook app on my iPhone? Please help me in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `not` necessary to have `Facebook app` in your device. But it is `necessary to use Facebook's new API`.

Older API's will `not work` any more.

Comment: Thanks Devang...Can you please tell me from where can I get the new Facebook's API?