# iPhone:facebook "misconfiguration" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

In my application I use sharekit for facebook integration. but It shows me an error msg as shown in below image.

[image: error message]

I want to clear that I have used latest library of sharekit and I have also referred following link
[referred link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496877/iphoneerror-of-misconfiguration-for-facebook-integration-occurs)

and as shown in fig. when I tap "Log in to Facebook" button I am able to send msg  to facebook.

but why does the message generate that I don't know.

Any kind of help would be appriciated..

Comment: This may be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528717/share-app-on-facebook/9528981#9528981

Comment: @Devang: I have read the API which you have suggested but the entire coding is in AppDelegate file but which code I have to write on button click(send to facebook) event.

Comment: There is one demo. Check its coding and make changes as per your need.

Comment: @Devang:plz send me the link of demo I am not able to find demo on that documentation

Comment: @KP : On facebook developer site, they have given github link for demo check that.